# How to obtain followed content with Microsoft Graph

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to fetch all the content that I am following (favorites) like sites and groups via the Microsoft Graph API. Like the content you get on the new SharePoint homepage `/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx?v=following`. I did not find anything like that on the https://graph.microsoft.io docs.

MemberOf `GET /users/<id | userPrincipalName>/memberOf` is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft Graph doesn't support to get the following content. If you want it to support this feature, you can submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

As workaround, you may consider use the SharePoint REST directly. We can use the **My/Followed** to get users, documents, sites, and tags that the current user is following.

Here is the sample REST for your reference:

```
GET http://<siteCollection>/<site>/_api/social.following/my/followed(types=15)
```

Request parameter

types

Type: Int32

The actor types to include. Users = 1, Documents = 2, Sites = 4, Tags = 8. Bitwise combinations are allowed.

More detail about SharePoint following REST, you can refer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn194080.aspx#bk_Followed).

Comment: That's great. It is not specifically for Microsoft Graph, but it is good enough for my case.